# Facebook Fb.ui feed - names, picture, caption not working in localhost

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

[image]
anyone who can help me.. my problem is when I share on facebook the picture didn't work what's wrong with my code.. I'm using localhost...

thanks in advance.

```
$('.testBtn').click(function() {
FB.ui({
      method: 'feed',
      name: 'Test Name',
      link: "http://192.168.1.149/", 
      picture: 'http://www.fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      caption: 'An example caption',
    }, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue now.. so it will help to others.. check the code i used below.

```
$('.testBtn').on('click', function() {
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.shares',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object : {
           'og:url': 'your url',
           'og:title': 'Test Title',
           'og:description': 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.',
           'og:og:image:width': '2560',
           'og:image:height': '960',
           'og:image': 'your image',
        }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: This is definitely the best (only?) option as of today (2018/02/01) to share a customizable story on facebook from within a single page application without server rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Those parameters are deprecated and will be taken from the OG tags of the shared URL. Read the changelog for v2.9 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/#v2_9

Comment: it works in OG tags but in FB.ui it is possible to work?

Comment: thanks it's work now. I use og:image in my Fb.ui thanks men!

Comment: in FB.ui it does not work anymore, you MUST use OG tags

Comment: luschn yeah.. but i use Fb.ui and use 'or:image': 'url' and it's work fine now.